# AJAX post to database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I have looked at other questions and cannot find the answer to why this isn't working. I am following a tutorial online. Here is my code:

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>AJAX Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h4>Enter an Item</h4>
<input type="text" id="item" /><br />
<input type="button" id="button" value="Submit" /><br />
<div id="content"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" scr="ajax.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS file:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
var item = $('#item').val();

$('#content').text('Loading...');

$.post('ajax.php', { item: item }, function(data) {
    $('#content').text(data);
    });
});
```

PHP file:

```
<?php
include 'db.php';

if (isset($_POST['item'])) {
    $item = $_POST['item'];
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO items(item)VALUES('$item')");
    if ($sql === true) {
        echo "Inserted into database";
    } elseif ($sql ==== false) {
        echo "Error inserting into database";
    }
 }
 ?>
```

I don't see what I'm doing wrong. The tutorial has the same code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Which the error throw it? 404 or 500?? . Also did  you debugg the script so can see if exits errors in the JavaScript

Comment: Include your <script> in the <head> section

Comment: You wrote `scr="ajax.js"` it should be `src="ajax.js"`

Comment: The millionth Ajax to Database question. What is the error? Is the Javascript called at all? Is the PHP script called, what error does mysql_error return? Etc. etc.

Comment: @Bouillou it's better to execute js at the end of the body, for a better loading performance.

Comment: @moonwave99 Performance isn't usually an issue in tutorials. Working code is, though, so if this code is literally the same as the one in the tutorial, you should search another tutorial.

Comment: @GolezTrol I just meant that moving scripts in `<head>` won't help fixing the problem either, and that actually it's better to leave them at the bottom.

Comment: @moonwave99: That's not always possible or even true. To the user, *perceived* loading time is what's important - and sometimes js is a factor in that. Waiting to load it can often cause a FOBUC.

Comment: @moonwave99 You're right about that, apart from WesleyMurch's sidenote.

Comment: I understand there are many questions on this as well and I searched them before posting but voting me down or saying its the millionth question is not useful so why bother wasting time and commenting? No error on the PHP side. I guess the JS is not being called. I will try what others have suggested.

Comment: Ugh stupid spelling mistake....GBD was right. Changing it to src worked. Sorry guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

moonwave99 is right (I'm not sure why the downvotes).. and also the scr="ajax" should be src="ajax" in your html and should be put in head or even before. Other reason may be the position of ajax.php to the site, maybe declaring whole URL will help :

```
$.post('http://wholeurl/ajax.php', { 
      item: item 
   }, function(data) {
      $('#content').text(data);
   });
```

Hope this helps, if not please specify error.

Answer (score 1):

Well i dont know if i can help you:

You have some mistakes on your code

1. The elseif condition is not ====(4) just ===(3)
2. The ajax.js file should be after the jquery library
3. The src attribute is not scr.
4. And of course the URL of the jquery library should start with http:// because is an external resource.
5. The mysql_query() function should have the conection variable, Example:
   mysql_query("[query here]", $connect);

Comment: You can use `src="//path/to/resource"` if you want to be protocol agnostic [see [HTML5 Boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/index.html)].

Answer (score 0):

Beside any other error you may get, you should import jQuery **before** your script:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
```

Comment: Useful unexplained downvoting is useful.

Comment: Wait, why are there 2 downvotes? This is a correct (although perhaps incomplete) suggestion. Can someone take a moment to explain please?