# Change CSS opacity with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So I have a heart icon that changes when you hover over it. Its fade into a full heart, instead of a stroke. Now for my project if you already liked the heart it would be solid pink by default. So what I planned on doing was check if the user liked it then raise the opacity. Because the solid icon goes from `0.1` to `1` on hover. The issue is I can't figure out how to set the if else statement.

```
<div class="post">
<? if($_SESSION['loggedIn'] == true): ?>
<a href="likes.php?id=<?php echo $post['id'];?>">
<div class="icons">
<i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>
<i class="fa fa-heart" ></i>
</div>
</a>
<? endif; ?>
```

That's what I currently have. What I'm trying to do is  if the user liked it, it would be true. Then

```
if(usr_liked == true){
  echo 'opacity: 1';
}
```

And that would lie in the style attribute in the heart. So how would I do this? I can't seem to figure it out with the alternative if else statement to display HTML.

Comment: `echo opacity: 1` will just print opacity: 1

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm trying to do... @imbondbaby

Comment: I meant it will literally print out on the page `opacity: 1`

Comment: Well its in the style tag. @imbondbaby

Answer (score 0):

You need PHP when loading the page

```
<? if(usr_liked == true){ ?>
    <i class="heart liked"></div>
<? } else { ?>
    <i class="heart not-liked"></div>
<? } ?>
```

and jQuery to change class if it is clicked

```
<script>
    $('.heart.not-liked').addClass('liked').removeClass('not-liked');
    $('.heart.liked').addClass('not-liked').removeClass('liked');
</script>
```

Your css should be

```
.heart.not-liked {
    color: grey;
}

.heart.liked {
    color: red;
}
```

The jQuery function could be better. But it works. Note: the jQuery function does not do anything with the database. You need to write an AJAX post for that.

Comment: Well the issue is how would I mix the HTML with the PHP?

Comment: You mean you want it to post it to the database without reloading the page? You need to do that with an ajax request: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13221200/ajax-post-to-database

Comment: No the database is all taken care of already. In your if else statement you mix PHP with HTML. Which doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to modify DOM styling, such as opacity in your case with PHP alone. You would want to do this with Javascript. One way that I've always done this is by simply calling a piece of Javascript code in a way similar to:

```
<?php if (usr_liked == true) { ?>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("heart").style.opacity = 1.0;' .
    </script>';
<?php } ?>
```

I hope this helps. :)

Note: I changed my original post as there was an error I found with it.

Comment: while perhaps not the best approach, it is far from impossible to apply style with php alone. Numerous ways it can be done

Comment: I've never seen it done with PHP alone. How would one go about doing it without Javascript?

Comment: could be written into an inline style attribute, or could create a `<style>` tag with conditional properties written in, or only write the style tag under certain conditions. Obscure but not impossible=> dynamic stylesheet

Comment: That makes sense and I guess it escaped my mind right now. Thanks for the correction, though. :)